# Merge Delete on joined tables is allowed but has a bug

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delete, merge, derived-tables

To start off, an updatable CTE, derived table or view may be the target of an `UPDATE` directly, even if it has multiple base tables, as long as all columns are from the same source table.

But they cannot be the target of a `DELETE`, even if columns from only one table are selected.

```
Msg 4405 Level 16 State 1
View or function 'x' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.
```

To get around this restriction, I attempted to use a `MERGE` against a dummy table.  (Obviously this simplistic example could be written using a `DELETE...WHERE EXISTS` or by putting one table as the merge source, but the point stands. The original used `ROW_NUMBER` so these weren't possible.)

```
WITH Joined AS (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON t2.id1 = t1.id1
)
MERGE Joined
USING (VALUES(0)) v(dummy) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rv8HO8gn)

This was actually allowed. But what I found was that the table that was modified did not depend on the columns being selected, or their order. It depended purely on the **order** that the tables were **joined**.

**This, to my mind seems completely buggy behaviour.**

Experimenting with `THEN UPDATE` shows far more sensible behaviour: it depends on which columns are used in the `THEN UPDATE` clause, in the same way as a normal `UPDATE` statement.

So, I think SQL Server should:

- Either continue allowing updatable CTEs to be deleted from, but ensure that only one table's columns are selected (like an `UPDATE`), ensuring no ambiguity.
- Or completely disallow `THEN DELETE` in `MERGE` when the source is an updatable CTE with multiple base tables.

**Do I have some misunderstanding in how updatable views work, or is there an actual bug here?**

---

**A bug report has now been filed on Azure Feedback. Please [vote for it here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/f7d44ff9-18b9-ee11-92bc-000d3a033659).**

Comment: Adding a `WHEN MATCHED` clause is also sufficient to change the table affected by the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE` clause (was wondering if the `MERGE` would end up modifying two different tables and this didn't happen) https://dbfiddle.uk/BL77Re5O

Comment: Interesting, that also seems to give the more consistent result I mention (ie only one table's columns can be present in all `UPDATE` clauses), and the `DELETE` clause then works on the same table. So that is a workaround.

Comment: @MartinSmith Posted here https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/f7d44ff9-18b9-ee11-92bc-000d3a033659

Answer (score 6):

From one point of view, your question is unanswerable because it depends on the `MERGE` design intent. There's nothing in the documentation to address this case explicitly.

My opinion is that `MERGE` ought to behave the same as the non-`MERGE` option; that is to say the `DELETE` [should be disallowed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql#arguments).

> *table_or_view_name*
> The name of the table or view from which the rows are to be removed.
>
> A table variable, within its scope, also can be used as a table source in a `DELETE` statement.
>
> The view referenced by *table_or_view_name* must be updatable and **reference exactly one base table in the `FROM` clause of the view definition**.

<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

The fact that `MERGE` doesn't produce an error here is probably because it is too hard for the parser to detect the condition. Or it's an oversight, as has been common with the exceptional complexity of `MERGE` variations.

In any case, my stance is you should avoid working around disallowed behaviours until you find something that 'works'. Or, you should not be surprised by any strange or non-deterministic results.

Report the issue as a bug to Microsoft so they can look into it.

Comment: Docs for MERGE itself say "If *target_table* is a view, any actions against it must satisfy the conditions for updating views. For more information, see Modify Data Through a View." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#target_table So I guess it does actually state that in the docs.

Comment: Would have thought "any actions" include a DELETE, and "must satisfy" means that existing restrictions on those actions. But the docs are anyway contradictory: [*Updatable Views*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#updatable-views) says "Any modifications, including UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, must reference columns from only one base table." and nothing else, which implies that it's actually dependent on the columns the view is selecting, not the `FROM`. So the existing error for a normal DELETE contradict that.

Comment: I agree the docs are not clear on it.